# Symfony2 custom data in security context is being overwritten by symfony

Tags: security, symfony, session

I have a method where security context is set using custom data:

```
$userEntity = new User();
$userEntity->fromArray($user);

$token           = new UsernamePasswordToken($userEntity, $userEntity->getPassword(), 'secured_area', $userEntity->getRoles());
$session = $this->container->get('session');
$session->set('_security_secured_area', serialize($token));

$this->container->get('security.authentication.manager')->authenticate($token);
$this->container->get('security.context')->setToken($token);
```

I use curl to get user data from another application and want to store it as local "logged user". 
It works, but after page reload/redirect in security.context I get new data from my local Database for the user with the same Id.

I imagine it can look complicated, so the question is:

Why when I run `$this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser()` Symfony gets user from Database, and not from Session?

Comment: On each page request, the security system calls userProvider.refresh which (by default) reloads the use from the local database in case something about the user has changed.  You best bet would be to plug in your own provider and override refresh to keep your custom data.

Comment: And the code you posted is probably not doing what you want.  In particular, you are not actually authenticating anything.  Furthermore, dealing directly with the security context means you are bypassing quite a bit of the security system.

Comment: Thanks for the help and some hints.